# Mat-Tab-Group not adding arrows in tabs-header

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I am dynamically adding tabs in mat-tab-group. The mat-tab-header is not adding pagination controls when required and the content overflows. Can someone help me with what I am missing?

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab
    *ngFor="let category of allCategories"
    label="{{ category.categoryName }}">
    content of tabs
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[image: The content overflows in mobile-view]

Comment: can you create a stackblitz sample and share it?

Comment: Any idea why? I have same issue